# Disabling vertical (swipe) scrolling in a ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, win-universal-app, windows-10-mobile

I am developing an application on the UWP primarily targeted to W10 mobile users, however I believe this issue will also be valid if attempted on a touchscreen W10 device.

I am using a ListView to lay out a set of buttons (ListViewItems, technically) which have text and an icon. They are in my SplitView and are used similar to how you see in the Windows default apps such as Groove Music and News, as pictured:

[image: Example from Groove Music]

It works perfectly as I'd hoped, except that if the user pulls up or down on the ListView with their finger it will 'squash' the list up or down - a useful animation for lists of emails, for example, but something undesirable on the UI of my program.

Is there a way of disabling this behaviour? If not, is there an alternative control that could suit my needs, or should I use a custom control?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set the `ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode` to `Auto` or `Disabled` on your `ListView`:

```
<ListView
    x:Name="ListView"
    ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Auto"
</ListView>
```

The default value is `Enabled` which will always "squash" the top and bottom. When set to `Auto`, then if there is no need to scroll (less elements than the viewport can fill), the "squash" effect will be disabled. And if you set the value to `Disabled`, then the scrolling will be disabled no matter how many elements need to be displayed.

For the official documentation see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br209589).

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I'm always surprised by how flexible XAML is.